# PHP Brackets error trouble

Tags: php, html, authentication, dreamweaver

Hello so my PHP script is giving me an error with the closing brackets on my if statements the error is as follows this is greatly hindering me and any help would be appreciated thanks.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE on line 40

```
if($numrows !=0) {
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $dbusername = $row['username'];
        $dbpassword = $row['password'];
    }

    if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==dbpassword) {
        echo "Login Successful. <a href='homepage.html'>Click Here to go to the home page</a>";
        $_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;
    }

    else {
        echo "Incorrect Login";
    }

    else {
        die ("This account does not exsist");
    }

    else {
        die ("Please enter a username and password");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: You have two `if` & three `else`, which can never possible. Always indent your code to easily recognize such errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `elseif`

please go through : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

for example :

```
if ($numrows != 0) {
  while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $dbusername = $row['username'];
    $dbpassword = $row['password'];
  }
  if ($username == $dbusername && $password == dbpassword) {
    echo "Login Successful. <a href='homepage.html'>Click Here to go to the home page</a>";
    $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
  } elseif ($username == '' || $password == '') {
    die("Please enter a username and password");
  } elseif (empty($dbusername)) {
    die("This account does not exsist");
  } else {
    die("Please enter a username and password");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have **3** `else` and I see only **2** `if`.

Try `else if (condtion){  }` where needed, or simply put all your code in a single `else`.

Presently, these `else` have no matching `if` and generate the `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE on line 40`

```
else{
die ("This account does not exsist");
    }

else{
die ("Please enter a username and password");
```